# How to use own map database to show a map on website?

Tags: dictionary

How to use own map database to display map on a website and use that map to find route and do other stuff ?

Comment: you will need a very large database

Comment: thats not a problem , please tell me how it is possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is an absolutely massive task, I'm not sure I understand your question correctly... You've tagged this with `Javascript`, `Web-development` and `map` - so presumably you want to know how to implement a front-end that renders a map to a web page, and then performs custom pathfinding and other logic. Surely I'm misunderstanding you! :D

Comment: i did some research and found lots of scripting is required for this. please tell me is it some way possible if i can use my own map for displaying on a web site and perform some action over it. what should be the approach to do so.

Comment: Well that would depend largely on the data you have in your map database. If you are storing bitmap images, rendering and tiling them isn't too hard, but you'd need a huge amount of positioning metadata. On the other hand, if you don't have images but only have some sort of data representation of vector co-ordinates or suchlike, you'll need to implement your own rendering algorithm! Which is beyond the scope of this question...

Comment: what would be the approach if i have my own bitmap image , how to show it on a web site

Comment: If I were you, I'd start by taking a look at the [canvas](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-canvas-element.html) element - that gives you the ability to position images wherever you want, and draw your own vector shapes (lines, ellipses etc) which could serve as your waypoint/path info on the map. Best of all, it's completely programmable in Javascript. Check out the [MDC tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial) for a great intro.

Answer (score 1):

You should try the Google Maps API. http://code.google.com/apis/maps/index.html

You can store locations or routes in your database and use the Maps API to display them. Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but I've found their API really easy to use.

Comment: as mentioned by me in my question that i want to use my own map database , please help me if you have any idea

Answer (score 0):

The O'rielly [RESTful Web Services](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596529260) book uses a map service as its operative example throughout the book, so you may find it useful, at least for the design of your service front end.  It doesn't delve into the implementation very deeply, particularly the actual mechanics of map image generation, as it is primarily concerned with the design of the service interface from an HTTP perspective.  It also doesn't treat very much with the client-side logic that would be involved in dragging, zooming and the like.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options in order to calculate routes depending on your database.
If your database has clean and accurate address names then you can easily use the google maps API that can be found here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/. 
Bare in mind that you can only execute 2500 requests per day with the free version.

On the other hand if you have a network defined on your db (have the roads in a nodes and arcs manner) then you can implement Dijsktra's algorithm.

Have a look here: http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaAlgorithmsDijkstra/article.html
Because of the fact that the network should be loaded from the database in order to calculate the best route I suggest the singleton pattern.

Answer (score 0):

An OpenSource way to do this, which I would recommend in most cases, is using [GeoServer](http://geoserver.org/display/GEOS/Welcome) and [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/).

GeoServer can read gegraphic data from all the major databases and be used as host for the widely used standard GeographicgWebServices [WMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Map_Service) and [WFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Feature_Service).

OpenLayers is a JavaScript API to show your map on the webpage.

Answer (score 0):

I recently implemented something like this. I realize it is an old question but Google has the javascript api v3 out for Google Maps and it works great.

https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3

This page helped me implement the entire system. Works great. You can also use php to update and edit the entries on the map.

You need xml pages and others but here is the map html page just to give you an idea of the javascript it entails.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html >
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>PHP/MySQL & Google Maps Example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[

    var customIcons = {
      restaurant: {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png',
        shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
      },
      bar: {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png',
        shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
      }
    };

    function load() {
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.6145, -122.3418),
        zoom: 13,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
      });
      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

      // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
      downloadUrl("phpsqlajax_genxml.php", function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
          var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
          var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
          var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
          var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            icon: icon.icon,
            shadow: icon.shadow
          });
          bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
        }
      });
    }

    function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
    }

    function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
      var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
          new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
          new XMLHttpRequest;

      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
          request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
          callback(request, request.status);
        }
      };

      request.open('GET', url, true);
      request.send(null);
    }

    function doNothing() {}

    //]]>

  </script>

  </head>

  <body onload="load()">
    <div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 300px"></div>
  </body>

    </html>
```